# How to free a TRIE?

Tags: c, pointers, free, trie

I'm currently working on a spell-checker (per CS50s pset5, for those who know it). I am using a TRIE to search, but am now having issues unloading it. The function fails the first time it tries to free(). My guess is that it tries to free the pointer and not what the pointer is pointing at, but I could be completely wrong.

My specific question is: Why does the `free()` function fail here? (Error: double free or corruption (out): 0x00000000006020c0 ***)

My definiton of a node:

```
typedef struct node
{
    bool wordHere;
    struct node* children[27];
}node;
```

My unload function:

```
node* currentNodePtr = &root;
bool unload(void)
{
    node* ptrArray[27] = {NULL};

    for(int i = 0; i < 27; i++)
    {
        ptrArray[i] = currentNodePtr -> children[i];
    }

    free(currentNodePtr);

    for(int c = 0; c < 27; c++)
    {
        if(ptrArray[c] != NULL)
        {
            currentNodePtr = ptrArray[c];
        }

        unload();
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: It will be much better to make `currentNodePtr` a parameter of `unload` instead of a global variable.

Comment: Unfortunately I am per my assignment not allowed to do this, but it would work a lot better, agreed! Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

It seems that the object `root` was not allocated dynamically.

So the pointer `currentNodePtr` does not point to a dynamically allocated object.

```
node* currentNodePtr = &root;
```

Hence you may not call

```
free(currentNodePtr);
```

for this pointer.

You have to allocate initially the object `root` dynamically as any other node.

A second problem that you have to include the recursive call of the function inside the if statement

```
    if(ptrArray[c] != NULL)
    {
        currentNodePtr = ptrArray[c];
        unload();
    }
```

because at the beginning of the function you do not check whether the pointer is equal to `NULL`.

Though it is better at the beginning of the function to check that the pointer `currentNodePtr` is not equal to `NULL`.

Also it is not a good idea when a function uses a global variable. Instead of using the global variable `currentNodePtr`  make it a parameter of the function.

Comment: Thank you! So I just have to use malloc to create the root and I should be good?

Comment: @MichaelKeller Yes you need to use malloc to create root. Also you have at least to include the recursive call of the function inside the if statement.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to all! The problem was, that the root node wasn't allocated dynamically.
I was unsure as to how I was supposed to allocate the root dynamically, so I used this simple (although not very elegant) fix:

```
node* currentNodePtr = &root;
bool unload(void)
{
    node* ptrArray[27] = {NULL};

    for(int i = 0; i < 27; i++)
    {
        ptrArray[i] = currentNodePtr -> children[i];
    }

    if(currentNodePtr != &root)
    {
        free(currentNodePtr);
    }


    for(int c = 0; c < 27; c++)
    {
        if(ptrArray[c] != NULL)
        {
            currentNodePtr = ptrArray[c];
            unload();
        }

    }

    return true;
}
```